# How to use $(window).load(function() instead of $(document).ready(function() when browser is IE

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a javascript code which I have written inside

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

and it runs fine on all browsers except IE. When I use

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

it runs fine on IE too but now as the code gets executed once each and every element, images etc have loaded completely the overall load time or turn around time has increased by a second or more.

How can I use window.load instead of document.ready only when browser is IE ?

**Note:: As the code is about 500 lines I just cannot use if else condition.**

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I would advise figuring out why IE is having the issue, since running a switch based on browser type is never perfect. IE supports jQuery 1.9.1 so there must be some other JS code hitting an error. When you open up the developer console in IE does it give you any specific errors?

Comment: well, you actually can just do an if/else.. you create a named function with your stuff in it and then after that, do an if/else and pass the named function instead of anonymous function with all your code. That way you don't have to double up on code.  But in any case, I agree w/ Alex.. I don't think the issue is with `document.ready`

Comment: @alex there is no error in the console,

Comment: @D555 When you run $(document).ready(function() in IE, you said there were issues. I assumed that meant there were JS related issues.

Comment: @alex by issue I mean only some of the images were not loaded but there was no javascript error

Comment: @D555 Well this doesn't sound like a JS issue.